# What is a good word for the "human thought of the era"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good word for the "human thought of the era"?

For example, I want to say that art is dependent on the human thought during its respective era.

Comment: What do you mean by "human thought"?

Comment: @alphabet: A thought that has occurred to one or more humans.

Comment: @Ricky So a thought that only a single person had, even privately, would qualify?

Comment: @alphabet: Especially if they had it privately. As in, "Is this shit for real?"

Comment: Are there non-human thoughts?

Comment: Are there human thoughts?

Comment: Answers elsewhere include 'zeitgeist', and 'spirit of the times', a phrasal synonym.

Answer (score 10):

English <strike>doesn't</strike> didn't have a (single)<sup>1</sup> word with the sought meaning. So we borrowed one from German...

> **zeitgeist**  <sup>([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist))</sup>
> *the general intellectual, moral, and cultural climate of an era*

---

<sup>1</sup> As [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zeitgeist%2Cspirit%20of%20the%20age&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) shows, we used to use the noun phrase ***spirit of the age*** - but we've switched pretty decisively to the German term in my lifetime...

[image]

(Note - the chart is "case-insensitive" because Zeitgeist is often capitalised.)

Comment: English does have a word with the sought meaning ***because*** we borrowed one from German. Otherwise German doesn't have one either so they stuck "time" and "ghost" together.

Comment: .According to [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zeitgeist%2Cspirit+of+the+times%2Cspirit+of+the+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the use of zeitgeist is recent (after 1990). it seems that it tends to replace the expression "spirit of the times" or "spirit of the age" defined as *the set of ideas, beliefs, and aims that is typical of people in a particular period in history* by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-spirit-of-the-age-the-spirit-of-the-times).

Comment: @hippietrail: Happy? :)

Comment: @Graffito: *Spirit of the **age*** was the main alternative. Zeitgeist actually became the more common choice in the late 70s, but your chart will have missed some matches because it was originally more likely to be capitalised (presumably, when people were less familiar with it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Blissful thx (-: Graffito: When using Google ngram viewer always try to think of capitalization and inflection variants. It has a case-insensitive option but not one for inflection. ["spirit of the times" is also very popular.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spirit+of+the+age%2Cspirit+of+the+epoch%2Cspirit+of+the+era%2Cspirit+of+the+time%2Cspirit+of+the+times%2Czeitgeist&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0)

Answer (score 0):

**ideology**

the body of doctrine, myth, belief, etc., that guides an individual, social movement, institution, class, or large group

As in "the dominant ideology of the epoch."

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ideology

**narrative**

a story that connects and explains a carefully selected set of supposedly true events, experiences, or the like, intended to support a particular viewpoint or thesis

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/narrative

Comment: An "ideology" is normally one of many (normally, *political*) *competing* ideologies vying for dominance within their era. So it's not so much the "thought of the era" - rather, each warring ideology is a *faction* within its era.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You do have a point. However, there's always a dominant one - or prevailing one, if you will. The one that you must pay lip service to even if you privately oppose it.

Comment: "ideology" has various meanings; [in Marxism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideology_and_Ideological_State_Apparatuses) it typically means the dominant thought system of those with all the money. But you'd probably want to qualify the word to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

***Cultural milieu*** is a phrase that describes the general cultural and social setting of a time and place. It doesn't necessarily refer to specific intellectual ideas like scientific theories of the day, but can encompass general attitudes and philosophies common among the population. The cultural milieu is linked to a specific place and time and captures the time-specificity you're looing for. It's not restricted to "thought", however, as the cultural milieu is also defined by the actions of the populace.

It fits very well in the example sentence that "Art is dependent on the cultural milieu," as it encompasses the many general and difficult-to-define aspects of culture which may be reflected in a work of art.